# Creating Arrows Jumping Left on Number Line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I need to put number lines with arrows jumping left for a maths exam. Please keep the `tikz` packages if possible. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /tkzlabelX/no zero/.style={
    /tikz/xlabel style/.append style={
      style/.expand once={\ifdim\tkz@pos pt=0pt shape=coordinate\fi}}},
  /tkzlabelY/no zero/.style={
    /tikz/ylabel style/.append style={
      style/.expand once={\ifdim\tkz@pos pt=0pt shape=coordinate\fi}}},
  /tkzAxeXY/no zero/.code=, /tkzdrawX/no zero/.code=, /tkzdrawY/no zero/.code=,
  /tkzlabelX/make an O/.style={
    /tikz/xlabel style/.append style={
      style/.expand once={\ifdim\tkz@pos pt=0pt
        shape=rectangle, fill=none, fill/.code=, % no filling, please
        pos=.5, yshift=+3pt, anchor=south east, % counter default xlabel style
        inner sep=+.3333em, /utils/exec=\def\tkz@Xresult{$O$}\fi}}},
  /tkzAxeXY/make an O/.code=, /tkzlabelY/make an O/.code=,
  /tkzdrawX/make an O/.code=, /tkzdrawY/make an O/.code=}
\makeatother
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=purple,      
    urlcolor=RoyalBlue,
    pdftitle={Math AT1 Year 7},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\showdiv[1]{\overline{\smash{\hstretch{.5}{)}\mkern-3.2mu\hstretch{.5}{)}}#1}}
\let\ph\phantom
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (-5.5,0) -- (10.5,0) ; 
\foreach \x in  {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} 
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};
\draw[*-*] (4.92,0) to[out=20, in=160] (10.08,0);
\draw[*-*] (0.92,0) to[out=20, in=160] (5.08,0);
\draw[*-*] (-2.08,0) to[out=20, in=160] (1.08,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My output:[image]
Wanted output (without changing font, ticks, or slopes of the curves, but enlarge arrows and add arrow to left of -2): [image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please take note that there's a different between TikZ and Tkz. TikZ commands are `\path`, `\draw`, `\fill` and so one. Tkz builds upon TikZ and its commands start with `\tkz`. Your code here doesn't use Tkz at all so all the `\pgfkeys` from my previous answer don't have anything to do with the diagram you have in your question. (At least so far.)

Comment: Do you want something like `\draw[*-*] (4.92,0) to[out=90, in=90] (10.08,0);`. You can use the parameter `looseness` to change the curve that's drawn.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That looks much better now, but is there a way to draw the arrow in the wanted output to the left of -2? (I'm updating the question now)

Comment: `\draw[*->] (2.08,0) to[out=180, in=0] + (-1,1);` where the `+` denotes a relative coordinate.